# Working on Josephus problem, Node function not working

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list, circular-list

I'm working on an assignment based on the Josephus problem and circular linked lists. The function below gives an error in Xcode (Control reaches end of non-void function) which I assume means that I need a return statement. However, when I add one, it doesn't accept it. But when I try the code in online compilers it works fine.

```
Node *newNode(int data)
{
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->next = temp;
    temp->data = data;
}
```

Comment: What's the return statement you're trying - just `return temp;`? When you say "it doesn't accept it", what is the error specifically?

Comment: Your function claims to return a `Node *`, so *of course* you need a `return` statement that returns such a pointer in that function. Why would you think you would not need that?

Comment: You need that `return` statement. If adding it exposes another bug, so be it. Keep the `return` and fix the other bug. What exactly the other bug is... Well, we can't help you without more information. Preferably in [mcve] form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `return temp;` at the end:

```
Node *newNode(int data)
{
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->next = temp;
    temp->data = data;
    return temp;
}
```